# Caching full response on the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Here's a very small sample Razor Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>
    @DateTime.Now.ToString()
</h1>

//model
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

If I use this code, the time will update every 30 seconds which is what is intended:

```
<cache expires-after="TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)">
    <h1>
        @DateTime.Now.ToString()
    </h1>
</cache>
```

However, adding the `ResponseCache` attribute to the model doesn't do this:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

After doing some research it seems like the attribute only sends the appropriate headers to the client, asking it to cache the content. How can I store the entire response in memory so when the user asks for the specific page, the server just sends the cached response and eliminate the process of computing the result again?

Also, with the `<cache>` tag helper, I couldn't find a way to invalidate the cached entry. So one scenario for me would be to cache every single page in memory for 30 days and if I change something on the admin panel, I would then invalidate the cache for that specific item so the next request would produce the fresh result. I used to do this on Asp.Net MVC 3+ but couldn't find any method to achieve the same result in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Comment: you can use Redis, or NCache to store data. after you can invalidate redis or ncache

Comment: Have you tried using the **vary-by** attribute of the <cache> tag? Any change to the object that it references should invalidate the cached content of the tag.

Comment: @Onur I'd prefer to use the framework itself but if it's not possible, please post a sample code. Thanks

Comment: @JohnM I could use that but I want to cache the whole page before it hits the "OnGetAsync()" Because the majority of the bottleneck is from getting data from the DB, not the rendering part. Althought I could cache an action but it seems like a bad idea. Also, using "vary-by" would still keep the cache data in memory not clear it.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I'm trying  https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor to cache database access using is automagic configuration option to cache all by default and letting it invalidate the cache when it is needed. I hope it works...

Comment: The cache is not decided only by server, if client side send headers described in this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http-headers-used-by-response-caching-middleware , response cache middleware won't take effort, can you check what headers your client send back to you?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you might need to roll out your own version

> How can I store the entire response in memory so when the user asks
>   for the specific page, the server just sends the cached response and
>   eliminate the process of computing the result again?

See the source of 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ResponseCacheAttribute.cs

And

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d8c6c4ab34e1368c1b071a01fcdcb9e8cc12e110/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ResponseCacheFilter.cs

It seems that it sets headers only.

You may implement your own version of caching like this one

https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/custom-response-caching-in-asp.net-core-with-cache-invalidation

See **CachedPage** class in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: No, it doesn't work (I cannot delete this answer).

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/performance/caching/middleware/samples/3.x/ResponseCachingMiddleware

> Browsers often add a cache control header on reload that prevent the
>   middleware from serving a cached page.

Therefore, it doesn't work and I don't see how this could be any useful besides machine-machine requests using specially crafted requests.

> Use a developer tool that permits setting the request headers
>   explicitly, such as Fiddler or Postman.

---

I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like the "Response Caching Middleware" could be the answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> For server-side caching that follows the HTTP 1.1 Caching
>   specification, use Response Caching Middleware. The middleware can use
>   the ResponseCacheAttribute properties to influence server-side caching
>   behavior.

Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> The middleware determines when responses are cacheable, stores
>   responses, and serves responses from cache.

You'll not always get a cached response, though.

> The middleware respects the rules of the HTTP 1.1 Caching
>   specification. The rules require a cache to honor a valid
>   Cache-Control header sent by the client. Under the specification, a
>   client can make requests with a no-cache header value and force the
>   server to generate a new response for every request. Currently,
>   there's no developer control over this caching behavior when using the
>   middleware because the middleware adheres to the official caching
>   specification.

In addition

> Caching should only be enabled for content that doesn't change based
>   on a user's identity or whether a user is signed in.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Interestingly in Asp.Net MVC 5 I could easily do this by the framework itself

Comment: The <cache> tag helper works fine, better than nothing, in partial views. I'm also caching database access using https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor